Using ffmpeg, how can I burn in one of multiple SRT subtitles tracks while also using -filter-complex?
The general instructs for burned-in subtitles are found here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo
I've used the instructions for picture-based subtitles successfully many times. But now that I need to burn in SRT subtitles, I can't use the above instructions for two reasons:

I need to use a complex (-filter-complex) filter at the same time, which can't be combined with a simple (-vf) filter.
The subtitle track I want to burn is one of multiple tracks embedded in video source, so even if subtitles=video.mkv worked, that method doesn't allow a specific subtitle track number to be specified.

Is there something like the -filter-complex option [0:v][0:s:1]overlay[v] that would work with SRT and other text-based, non-picture subtitles?

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles → try → ffmpeg -i "input.mkv" -vf " subtitles='input.mkv:si=0':force_style='Bold=1,MarginV=10', subtitles='input.mkv:si=1':force_style='Bold=0,MarginV=40' " -c:a copy /tmp/out.mp4

Ah, I figured it out.
ffmpeg -y -i source.mkv -c:v vp9 -row-mt 1 -crf 24 -s 720x480 -sar "32:27" \
    -filter_complex "[0:v]zscale=t=linear:npl=100,format=gbrpf32le,zscale=p=bt709, \
        tonemap=tonemap=hable:desat=0,zscale=t=bt709:m=bt709:r=tv,format=yuv420p[v0]; \
        [v0]subtitles=source.mkv:si=1[v]" -map "[v]" -an -dash 1 \
    -map_chapters -1 -f webm out.webm

I didn't realize that close to the same syntax as is used for a simple filter can be added to a complex filter, so long as you use the proper parameter naming to chain the filter components.
I also learned that the file name of a video with multiple embedded subtitle tracks can be supplemented with a track selector in the form :si=index.
I'm using this command to generate pre-converted video streams at various resolutions for adaptive streaming. The non-subtitle part of the filter is for converting HDR video to SDR.
